How to exclude folders and file path from mend scan
I have been trying to use the syntax below in the whitesource.config file to exclude folder path from scanning in mend.
Syntax - excludes=/path/
Above syntax is mentioned in the devkit for Mend.
Example: excludes=/db/postgres/ **/*sources.jar **/*javadoc.jar
I have tried it with/without quotes. 
Is there anything else needs to be taken care which is missing from devkit? 
Has anyone been successful in excluding folders/jar files from scanning?
I have tried to update the path in whitesource.config as per the syntax in devkit
